# Can you add a button or link to a Custom action to a display form page using script Editor

Tags: 2013, javascript, content-editor-web-part, script-editor-webpart

I would like to trigger a custom action via a link or button on the form page.

Yes, I have already created a button/icon in the ribbon.

But what I want to do is create a button on the page front and center, thereby minimizing the need for the person to hunt down the icon in the ribbon.

I have google searched this and everything leads back to the button/icon on the ribbon.

I do not have InfoPath or any other way to edit the page besides installing new web parts (content editor, script editor).  I am working with SharePoint 2013/2010 form pages.

Simple Jscript would be preferred, and if you could explain the programming it would be appreciated as some of my form pages have multiple custom actions in the ribbon and I may only want one or two front and center.

Comment: What does your custom action button in the Ribbon do?  Does it execute some Javascript code?

Comment: The button creates an item in another list.  None of the buttons do anything other than trigger a custom action workflow associated with the item being viewed in display or edit.

Comment: But how?  Sorry if I was not specific enough, but what I am asking is not "what is the end goal of your Ribbon button", but more along the lines of: technically speaking, what does your Ribbon button immediately do when it is clicked?  Are you using a `UrlAction` or a `CommandUIHandler` with a `CommandAction`?  If you are using a `CommandUIHandler`, what is the `CommandAction` itself?

Comment: Button when clicked opens Workflow initiation form.  I am not sure what SPD 2013 uses to create this.